# How to remove <code style="display: none;"> </code> from HTML in Vim?

Tags: html, vim

I have an HTML like this:

```
<div id="content" style="cursor: pointer;">
<code style="display: none;"> </code><code style="display: none;"> </code><code style="display: none;"> </code><code style="display: none;"> </code><code style="display: none;"> </code><code style="display: none;"> </code><div class="container clearfix">
<code style="display: none;"> </code><code style="display: none;"> </code><code style="display: none;"> </code><code style="display: none;"> </code><code style="display: none;"> </code><code style="display: none;"> </code> <code style="display: none;"> </code>
```

I tried doing this in Vim:

```
:%s/\<code style="display: none;"\> \</code\>//g
```

But Vim tells me that there are trailing characters.

What's the correct way or removing these tags?

Comment: If your example is just this small, I'd go to the `<div` with `$F<` and do `d0` and then `jdd`. Oh but it looks like you're missing the `\ ` in `\<\/code\>`

Answer (score 1):

I find if replacing in HTML, it's easier to use one of the command separators other than /.

e.g.

```
:%s+<code style="display: none;"> </code>++g
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to escape the characters that you are escaping. In fact, `\<` is an escape sequence for vim regular expression word boundaries. You just want to use `<`.  `/` does need to be escaped if you're using it as a command separator, but that's all.

```
:%s/<code style="display: none;"> <\/code>//g
```

If you want to remove all of the `<code>` blocks no matter what is in them you can use `>.*</code>` to greedily remove from the first to final start and end tags on each line. If you have other stuff between each tag you may not want to erase, you can use a reluctant/non-greedy quantifier instead:

```
:%s/<code style="display: none;">.\{-}<\/code>//g
```

Without knowing exactly what the page you are trying to edit looks like it's hard to offer more advice, but in the case above you could just delete those two lines since there's nothing useful on them. You can also use `dat` to delete individual tags.

Answer (score 0):

Place your cursor on the first character of your tag (i.e. the `<`):

```
<code style="display: none;">
```

Now

- `df>` or
- `d%`

`f>` is super useful:

- It [`f`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#f)inds the given character in the current line (forward)
- To use it backward, use `F<`
- To move the cursor un[`t`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#t)il a character, use `t>`. In your example, this places the cursor on the `"` right before the closing `>`

Also, the [`%`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#%25) move is very handy. It finds a matching item. Closing brackets, `#endif` statements for the `#if` under the cursor and so on.

Comment: I think `dat` is much easier to delete a single tag, it will remove the whole `<code xxx> </code>` thing.